# Python Scikit learn - Don't want random split using train_test_split

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I use Scikit learn train_test_split and random forest for modelling.
I have already set the fixed number in random_state of train_test_split, let say random_state=1, but it still generates different result every running. I want a fixed result for comparison of models. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "different result"?  I recommend trying to print a short preview of the training/testing set before you pass it along to your training code.  For instance:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25 random_state = 1)
print(X_train[:10])
```

I can confirm that this code will produce the same exact X_train set across multiple runs.

However, if by "different result" you mean the training error is different, you might want to make sure you're fixing the random seed for the random forest classifier as well.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't fix the random seed for the random forest classifier.